# Como mostrar uma coluna, mas se tiver nulo mostrar outra sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Como mostrar uma coluna, mas se tiver nulo mostrar outra sql
como Exemplo uma tabela com o nome tarefas.

> ```
> | id  |  nome    |  nome resumido |
> +-----+----------+----------------+
> | 1   | nome 1   | 1              |
> | 2   | nome 2   | 2              |
> | 3   | nome 3   | null           |
> ```

o sql vai pegar o nome resumido, onde estiver null ele pega o nome por exemplo:

> ```
> |  id | as nome  |
> +-----+----------+
> | 1   |  1       |
> | 2   |  2       |
> | 3   |  nome 3  |
> ```

Caso não consiga no sql eu estou usando a linguagem em php

Comment: Já conhece a função `coalesce`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como comentado na própria pergunta, pode ser feito utilizando o **[COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)**:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(nome_resumido, nome) as nome
FROM nome_tabela
```

Também é possível utilizar o **[IFNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)**:

```
SELECT id, IFNULL(nome_resumido, nome) as nome
FROM nome_tabela
```

Além desses, como sugerido em outra resposta, pode ser feito usando o **[CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp)**:

```
SELECT id, 
    CASE nome_resumido is null THEN nome
    ELSE nome_resumido END as nome
FROM nome_tabela
```

Comment: Eu usei está e foi muito simples e mais facil, outra opção que tinha achado foi no codigo em php, porém em sql ficou menor o codigo.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo você pode utilizar o CASE do mysql:

```
SELECT nome, nome_resumido,
  CASE
    WHEN nome_resumido IS NULL OR nome_resumido = '' THEN nome
    ELSE nome_resumido
  END AS Nome
FROM Users;
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se percebi bem mas.

Percisas de usar o ISNULL/function operator.

```
Select ISNULL(a, b)
```

`b` é selecionado if `a` for Null.

Até podes usar o WHEN/THEN uma opção do Select, procura melhor o "BOL".

Essencialmente: É o c switch/case bloco no SQL.